# Create new SVG Element after transition using D3

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg, transition

Basically this a question of chained transition but it has to create a new element(e.g. circle) after the duration of the first transition ends. I would like to implement it using the recommended way of chain transitions (without using the "end" listener)

This is what I currently have. I can't seem to locate any examples around the net that will create a new element without using the "end" listener.

```
     var svgContainer = d3.select("body")
                      .append("svg")
                      .attr("width",300)
                      .attr("height",300);

     var svgLine = svgContainer.append("line")
                               .attr("x1", 1)
                               .attr("y1", 1)
                               .attr("x2", 5)
                               .attr("y2", 1)
                               .attr("stroke-width", 2)
                               .attr("stroke", "black");

      var lineAnimation_1 = svgLine.transition()
                                 .duration(2000)
                                 .attr({x2:400,y2:1});
```

Comment: I don't see a way of doing this with chained transitions.

Comment: oh i see, thanks for the response. Maybe I should stick to the "end" listener and execute a callback.

Comment: Is there a specific reason for you not wanting to use the end callback ? It's the de-facto standard way of hooking onto animation ending.